# Facebook scraper returns wrong page

Tags: facebook

When I enter the URL of a page of my website in Firefox, I get to see the right page in the browser (page A). Same thing in Chrome/Safari/Opera. When I use wget in Ubuntu, I get page A. When I use Fetch as Google, it scrapes page A.

So why does Facebook shows an entirely other page (page B)? When I use Facebook Sharing Debugger, it shows me the right Fetched URL (page B), but a wrong Canonical URL (page B). The canonical URL of page A is the right one, though.  When clicking on 'See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL', I see page B. It return an response code 200, so it doesn't seems like there's some redirection. **What can affect the Facebook **scraper** and none of the other bots/browsers?**

I did an update of Wordpress two weeks ago, so it must the culprit. But I have trouble understanding where and what to fix. If you need example, all our recipe's pages (like [this one](https://www.soscuisine.com/recipe/grandma-cream-tomato-soup-less-sodium)) get redirected in Facebook to our [recipe search](https://www.soscuisine.com/recipe/search/) page. But other pages, like the blog posts, get parsed correctly.

Comment: Because that is what you specified that your og:url is.

Comment: @WizKid Where can-you see that? When I view the source of the page in Firefox, the og:url is fine

Comment: Using https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.soscuisine.com%2Frecipe%2Fgrandma-cream-tomato-soup-less-sodium and click on "See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL" which takes you to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/echo/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.soscuisine.com%2Frecipe%2Fgrandma-cream-tomato-soup-less-sodium

Comment: Your site uses the Yoast SEO plugin to output the OG meta data, so go check the settings for that. It might be configured to send the Facebook scraper (easily recognizable by its User-Agent) to a different URL for whatever reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your feedback. It was in fact a trailing slash error in the redirection. It seems that the Facebook scraper automatically add a slash at the end.